# download mp3 from google translate text to speech in Albanian

Tags: mp3, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to download mp3 files from Google translate using the Albanian country code "al"

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=al&q=dritare
```

but I get

```
video playback aborted due to a network error
```

I'm using Firefox and windows 7.

I use this method successfully with other languages for example Italian

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=it&q=esercito
```

and then I can download the mp3 just fine. I have also tried English and Greek.

Albanian text to speech it is supported by Google translation and I can hear the text pronounced in Albanian when I press the sound icon.

I have also tried in Chrome and it isn't working there either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code for the Albanian language is "sq" not "al" which is the country's code. So if you type for example

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=sq&q=po
```

everything works fine!